# Consuming RESTful services with SSL on Android

Tags: android, tomcat, ssl-certificate, jax-rs

I have created an app which would get data from my DB through RESTful services.

What I have tried is I have implemented SSL on service level using self-signed certificate (for now) and in order for android app to communicate with services, I have imported same SSL certificate in my  android application.

I wanted to confirm about my approach and also is it secure option because I think someone can get the certificate from android app by reverse-engineering. If no what will be the most secure option to do that?

Comment: What certificate are you talking about ? The server certificate ? Then whatever you put in the app is public and it doesnt matter.

Comment: thanks to reply , i have crated a dummy SSL certificate by using the keystore command, and placed and configured it in tomcat server to enable SSL and same certificate put on android to make successful communication .